# Python Flask automatically shut down during the process of triggering xlsx generation and serve file repository

Tags: python, excel, flask, web

I am using Flask to build a web app. One of the things I need to achieve described as below:

1. Trigger a button from html/js to tell flask to go off trigger Python to generate an xlsx (using pandas' ExcelWriter: `pd.ExcelWriter(xlsx_path)`)
2. Python the go grab data then generate xlsx to a folder
3. Flask then serve this folder using `from flask import send_from_directory`

Problem:

- Step #1 works fine. I can see the function to generate xlsx is being triggered.
- Step #2 and #3 will usually just stop, because Flask suddenly shut itself down ... Then I need to start flask back up then Step #2&3 got through successfully.

Please will you be able to point me to what caused Flask to shut down automatically when goes to step #2&3?

More details below.

The code to trigger xlsx download:

```
from flask import request
@app.route('/api/xxx', methods=['POST'])
def xxx():
    req_data = request.get_json()
    func_output_xlsx(req_data)
```

The code to serve the xlsx newly generated:

```
@app.route('/files/<path:filename>')
def send_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory('output', filename)
```

Command to open Flask:

```
set FLASK_ENV=development
set FLASK_APP=app.py
python -m flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=5000
```

Environment:

- Python version: 3.7.0
- Flask version: 1.1.2
- Pandas version: 0.24.2

Comment: Did you get any error output in the terminal? What's "Flask suddenly shut itself down" actually mean?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure every view function has a valid return statement:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/api/xxx', methods=['POST'])
def xxx():
    req_data = request.get_json()
    func_output_xlsx(req_data)
    return ''  # <--
```